# Getting error in condition formatting using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project in which I am comparing column D with column C of sheet("Backend") and the difference is shown in column E (in %). I'd like to highlight the % difference (column E) in RED color, where the difference is less than -10.00% and greater than 10.00%. Then would like to copy those items from column B corresponding each highlighted cell and paste it in sheet("UPDATER") beneath cell A7.

Attached is the screenshot for your reference

[image]

```
Sub check_date()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wsData As Worksheet, Datasht As Worksheet, lRow As Integer


Set wsData = Sheets("UPDATER")
Set Datasht = Sheets("Backend")
lRow = Datasht.Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row


wsData.Range("M8:M" & lRow).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
wsData.Range("M8:M" & lRow).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(M8>=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1,M8<EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1))"
wsData.Range("M8:M" & lRow).FormatConditions(wsData.Range("M8:M" & lRow).FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
 With wsData.Range("M8:M" & lRow).FormatConditions(1).Interior
 .Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
 .TintAndShade = 0
 End With
 wsData.Range("M8:M" & lRow).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
 Range("M8").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: "getting error" is not a very useful description of the exact problem you're having? If there's an error message, what is it, and which line is highlighted when you press "Debug" ?

Comment: 1) Datasht.Range("E" & lRow).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=-0.1"



2) Datasht.Range("E" & lRow).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=0.1"
    these two lines are actually aint doing much, no cell in column E gets highlighted as per the defined condition thus no row is getting filtered as per colour filter and copied to another sheet.

Comment: I'm no expert but it looks like everything you are doing is only to the last row in column E. Should be more like `Range("E1:E" & lRow)` etc. But I would use a `For` loop going from start to end checking if its greater than 10% and less than -10%. Then just use standard conditional formatting to change the text colour if you want that. For loop is cleaner, quicker and easier than autofilter in my opinion.

Comment: I have tried using for loop and getting "type mismatch error" i have also attached a screengrab for your reference.

Comment: Tried your loop myself and worked fine. You didn't dim your cell. Try `Dim cell As Variant`

Comment: but seems like the values in column E are not getting highlighted as per the cell value given in the code, it should highlight if cell value is less than -10% or grater than 10% but I can see even 0.088% is getting highlighted however it doesn't come  under the set criteria

Comment: Also once the values get highlighted, i am looking to copy those values starting from column B till column E then paste it to UPDATER sheet beneath cell A7. i have updated the code for your reference.

Comment: Rethink what percent represents (translation: 1% is the 100th part of  a value -> 1  => 100%)! To compare with a number divide by 100! Also read on [Abs()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/abs-function) function then use it to have only one expression that checks <-19% and >10%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I got. It's a bit of a drastic change but I'm hoping this is actually what you're going for.

```
Sub formatcondition()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wsData As Worksheet, Datasht As Worksheet, lRow As Integer, My_Range As Range, i As Integer, iRow As Integer, cell As Variant, RowNum As Long, lRowUpdater As Long

Set wsData = Sheets("UPDATER")
Set Datasht = Sheets("Backend")
lRow = Datasht.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
lRowUpdater = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
RowNum = 8 'setting the first row in the UPDATER sheet


Datasht.Range("E1:E" & lRow).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'Reset the color before running
wsData.Range("A8:D" & lRowUpdater + 8).ClearContents 'clear your updater sheet. Remove if not needed.

For i = 1 To lRow
    On Error GoTo Continue
    If Datasht.Range("E" & i).Value < -0.1 Or Datasht.Range("E" & i).Value > 0.1 Then 'If greater than or less than
        Datasht.Range("E" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'Change the color of affected cells if you need that
        wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(RowNum, 1), wsData.Cells(RowNum, 4)).Value = _
        Datasht.Range(Datasht.Cells(i, 2), Datasht.Cells(i, 5)).Value 'straight copy the values from the cells as it loops rather than using copy/paste
        wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(RowNum, 2), wsData.Cells(RowNum, 4)).NumberFormat = "0.00%" 'change the number format of outputted cells to percentages (if needed)
        RowNum = RowNum + 1 'move to the next row in the output
    End If
Continue:
Resume Nexti
Nexti:
Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

For the date to add a year my version would be just adding to what I gave earlier. Instead we now add an `AND` function to contain the `OR`, then checking if the `YEAR` in the cell is the current year. If you're only wanting this year then we can also forgo the IF statement which was checking that if the current month was January it would incorporate December. But if thats not needed then:

`=AND(OR(MONTH(NOW())=MONTH(M8),MONTH(NOW())-1=MONTH(M8)),YEAR(M8)=YEAR(NOW()))`

Or

`=AND(MONTH(M8)>=MONTH(NOW())-1,MONTH(M8)<MONTH(NOW())+1,YEAR(M8)=YEAR(NOW()))`

Both the same length and do the same thing just in different way.

Comment: Thankyou so much simon for your help, i have tested the code its works like a charm when I run it using F8 key , but when i use F5 key it stops and give an error message of TYPE MISMATCH at this line of code.

If Datasht.Range("E" & i).Value < -0.1 Or Datasht.Range("E" & i).Value > 0.1 Then 'If greater than or less than

Comment: i think i got the reason, column E (sheet Backend) can also have #NA values which is why it is showing Type Mismatch error.

Comment: to combat this i have used =IFERROR(D1-C1),"") to make the #NA cells blank, can we do something so it should not copy #NA/Blank cell values to UPDATER sheet?

Comment: Ahh I didn't clear the error in case there were more. I only tested against one error so I didn't see the issue. Basically below the `Continue:` add `Resume Nexti` Then `Nexti:` and it will work. Resume tells Excel to continue the code as is. I've updated the answer as well.

Comment: can we add a code to highlight the dates in column M which are occurring this month or occurred previous month. i have tried using conditional formatting but didn't help.

Comment: Use this formula in your conditional formatting because it's just easier than coding it out and it's done automatically: `OR(MONTH(NOW())=MONTH(A1),IF(MONTH(NOW())-1=0,12,MONTH(NOW())-1)=MONTH(A1))`. Just remember to select the range you want it for and change "A1" in the code to whatever the first cell is in the range.

Comment: Also for future reference. Can you not try to edit the persons answer. Instead edit your own question then comment to the person.

Comment: i am using this =AND(M8>=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1,M8<EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)) but it does not highlight current month value i.e. september

Comment: and the one which you gave highlights for the last 2 months but I guess it skips the year factor, I can see it is also highlighting dates from Aug 2016 however I am looking for the last 2 month only for this particular year

Comment: I have attached a new screenshot and the vba code that I have built-in my original post, can you pls have a look.

Comment: I updated my answer with edited version of yours and edited version of mine. I wouldn't use EOMONTH. Are you just looking for generic last 2 months (as in currently August/September) or are you wanting like the last 60 days. Cause if you want that then probably use `TODAY()-60` or something instead of the month factor.

Comment: the formula worked but when i put the same formula in the mentioned code in my original post, its doesn't work

Comment: So what do you want the actual date range to be? Do you want it to be from the first of a month to the current date? For example from 1st August to today 15th Sept. That would be `=AND(M8>=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1,M8<=TODAY())` . Cause currently your code only works for 1st Aug to 30th Aug.